# Converting NSString into uint8_t

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on data encryption sample code provided by Apple in the "*Certificate, Key and Trust Programming guide*". The sample code for encrypting/decrypting data considers an `uint8_t`. However the real world application would be doing this on an `NSString` object. I have been trying to convert `NSString` object to `uint8_t` but every-time I try I get a compiler warning. Solutions given for 'almost' same problems given in various forums, don't seem to work for me.

Comment: show us the code that you tried and "almost" didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example of turning any string value into a `uint8_t*`. The easiest way is to just cast the bytes of NSData as and uint8_t*. Other option is to allocate memory and copy the bytes but you will still need to track the length somehow.

```
NSData *someData = [@"SOME STRING VALUE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const void *bytes = [someData bytes];
int length = [someData length];

//Easy way
uint8_t *crypto_data = (uint8_t*)bytes;
```

### Optional way

```
//If you plan on using crypto_data as a class variable
// you will need to do a memcpy since the NSData someData
// will get autoreleased
crypto_data = malloc(length);
memcpy(crypto_data, bytes, length);
//work with crypto_data

//free crypto_data most likely in dealloc
free(crypto_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *stringToEncrypt = @"SOME STRING VALUE";
uint8_t *cString = (uint8_t *)stringToEncrypt.UTF8String;
```