# IOS:convert value string value to Unit_8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, hex, crc

i have string value as @"hello world ".I need to pass string value along with crc commands my crc commands are here .I have converted string like this

```
         Nsstring * total=@"hello world ";
         uint8_t *cString =  (uint8_t *)[total UTF8String];

                             Byte comm[5];
                             comm[0]=0x01;//START_BYTE_LEN
                             comm[1]=0X06;//PACKET_LENGTH_LEN
                             comm[2]=0x62;//COMMAND_ID_LEN
                             comm[3]=0x00;//SUB_TYPE_LEN
                             comm[4]=cString; //STRIN_len
                             comm[3]=-59;//CRC_LEN
                             comm[4]=-91; //CRC_LEN
```

i am using these commands and writing to peripheral device in response to that i am getting the values as  `011e6300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e5e2` .
     i am getting the actual response as **63** but when i have passed the string values 
      all the data is coming as zeros. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you passing the values?
Convert it like so:

```
NSData *someData = [@"HELLO WORLD" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const void *bytes = [someData bytes];
int length = [someData length];
uint8_t *cString = (uint8_t*)bytes;
```

And then back to string:

```
NSString *yourString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cString
                                       length:length
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",yourString); -----> HELLO WORLD.
```

See [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783258/4215623)

Comment: if  you print cstring also u will get hello world.there is no need to come back to string .But my question is different  i need to pass the data to commands and those commands i am keeping in array and writing it to peripheral